# Library reference to a library

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

In our project we are using a static library which intern uses another library.

Consider:

```
- MyProject uses MyLibrary
- Mylibrary uses BaseLibrary
```

Should I include my BaseLibrary to MyProject? If I give only interface reference to my project It works fine in desired way. Any problem would come if I add/Not add BaseLibrary to MyProject .

Comment: Does MyProject need BaseLibrary?

Comment: Yes, MyProject is also uses BaseLibrary

Comment: Won't you get symbol duplicate error when add the BaseLibrary in?

Comment: No, gets build successfully. For sure both libraries will consume some sort of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not add `BaseLibrary` to `MyProject` and it works fine. Then you don't have to ask yourself the question.

Whereas if it doesn't work without, so you must add it anyway.

Comment: My problem is any memory issue will come ? or any other issue will come ?

Comment: I don't get your problem. If it works, then it works. If you can launch your application, since they are static library, it means everything is ok.

Comment: It launches properly, everything works fine. Any memory issue would come is what my question?

Comment: No reason you have such an issue after. No worries.
After all, each of your 3 Project certainly import `NSFoundation`framework and some other (like `UIKit`), it doesn't present any issue anyway. So it's the same for your Library.

Comment: I have done a sample proj. Consider: libOne is 5kb libTwo is 5kb. Once I give libTwo reference to libOne, libOne size becomes 10kb. This is my problem statement. In framework case I m aware that you are only give the reference not adding it to the project.

Comment: You have two ways then, you can create true Framework out of your custom libs and then do references like you said. Use [iOS Framework](https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework#walkthrough)
Or you should interface your `BaseLib` in your `MyLib` but it is quite painful. In the end I really advise you to use iOS Framework, because it's always good to see your own lib looking like the on of Apple :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47868/discussion-between-user1554347-and-anc-ainu)